# Can't insert PHP SQL row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code, and I don't know what's wrong with it. It will create a new table with the game name if it isn't existing, and that's working. The second part, where we insert a row doesn't work.

```
// Create connection
$con=mysql_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_username","$mysql_password") or die("error");
mysql_select_db("$mysql_database") or die("database not found");

// Create the table if it doesn't exist
$game_exists = (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$game_name."'"))==1);
if($game_exists == false) {
    $game_name = mysql_escape_string($game_name);
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE '".$game_name."' (name text, data text)") or die("Could not create table");
    echo "Table created";
} else {
    $game_name = mysql_escape_string($game_name);
}

$name = mysql_escape_string($name);
$data = mysql_escape_string($data);
$sql = "INSERT INTO $game_name (name, data) VALUES ('$name', '$data')";

$result = mysql_query($test) or die("Select Error");
echo $result;
```

Each time, it dies on Select Error. The table exists

Comment: change `($name, $data)` to `('$name', '$data')`

Comment: I just have to mention, creating a table dynamically for each game isn't best practice when it comes to relational databases.

Comment: Thanks for telling Joachim

Comment: In addition to @JoachimIsaksson comment, if `$game_name` comes from user-input, this is a very bad idea as `mysql_escape_string` does nothing to sanitize a table- or column name.

Comment: About your problem, use a modern database API and enable / add error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$test` is not used anywhere else, it is undefined. I think you want to pass `$sql` instead.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Select Error");
```

Comment: Bah.. I should have seen that. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting quotes in your insert query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $game_name (name, data) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$data."')";
```

and also `$test` doesn't exist

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Select Error");
```